# XML Document validation fails on modified Document but passes when reparsed

Tags: java, xml, validation, schema

I have code that modifies an XML `Document` by adding an `Attribute` to an existing `Element`. Prior to the modification I run the `Document` through validation using `Schema` and `Validator` and it passes.

However, after I add the `Attribute` (which is valid per the schema) if I pass the `Document` instance to the `Validator` it fails.

If as an intermediary step I take the `Document` instance, convert it to a `String` and re-parse to a `Document`, this new `Document` passes validation.

I assume I should not have to do this. I tried using `normalizeDocument` and `normalize` and these didn't address the issue.

**Update**

I wrote a unit test that does nothing but validate the Document, adds the attribute and revalidates the Document. This passes. However, when I run the integration test that passes the Document through the whole system it fails per the above. Again, converting to a String and back to a Document passes validation.

The code is not in a location that I can paste it here and it seems that it is a broader issue since the unit test passes.

Any suggestions on where to investigate would be helpful.

Comment: How do you modify the document (DOM, JDOM, XSLT?) What is the exact validation error?

Comment: Using DOM. Attribute "x" is not allowed in element "y"

Comment: Hard to tell without a reproducible code example.

Comment: Sorry, can't cut/paste and unit test but integration test fails so wouldn't be something I could simply demonstrate.

Comment: You could try to replace or update the DOM implementation (e.g. using the latest XercesImpl instead of the Java builtin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with a namespace aware XML `Document`.

I was using `setAttribute(name, value)` to add non-namespaced attributes, which resulted in the same
Attribute "x" is not allowed in element "y" exception. Re-parse the document and the problem went away.

The fix was to use the namespace aware method [`setAttributeNS(namespaceURI, qualifiedName, value)`](http://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#setAttributeNS_java.lang.String__java.lang.String__java.lang.String_), passing `null` as the namespaceURI.

Comment: It would be grat to have a code example showing this function usage